# Is the operator $A$ self-adjoint? unitary? normal?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let the Hilbert space $H=l_2$ over the complex field.

Is the operator $A$ self-adjoint? unitary? normal?

$Ax=(x_1,ix_2,-x_3,-ix_4,x_5,....)$

could you please help.

Comment: Can you calculate $A^{\ast}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounded operator $A$ has a complete orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. So $A$ is normal. $A$ is not selfadjoint because the eigenvalues are not all real. $A$ is unitary because the range of $A$ includes the aforementioned orthonormal basis, and because $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$.

Answer (score 2):

1. For *self-adjointness* just compare $\langle Ax,y \rangle$ and $\langle x,Ay \rangle$.  You'll have to check whether $$
     \langle Ax,y \rangle
     = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(i^{k-1}x_k\right)\cdot \overline{y_k}
     \overset?=
     \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k\cdot\overline{\left(i^{k-1}y_k\right)}
     = \langle x,Ay \rangle \text{.}
   $$
   **Hint**: Let $x = y = (0,1,0,\ldots)$. Then $\langle Ax,y \rangle = \ldots$, but $\langle x,Ay \rangle = \ldots$
2. For unitarity you have to check that $$
     A^*A = AA^* = I \text{,}
   $$
   so you'll have to find the adjoint of $A$ and work out if this holds or not
3. For normality you only need the weaker identity $$
     A^*A = AA^* \text{.}
   $$